# How to connect row values of a matrix with an index for a parameter

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, simulation

I want to create a tables for a parameter ( lets say `X_n` for products from 1 to 3).
There are certain values that the parameter can take with a given probability value.

Considering `n = 1` I can simulate the values that `X_1` can take with the following code

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete 
values = [-2, 0, 2]
probabilities = [0.40, 0.2, 0.4]
distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
distrib.rvs(size=10)
```

This code returns following result:

> array([ 2, -2,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2])

Now I want to do it for the real case, where `n = 3`

I tried to create the tables as follows but failed;

```
num_products=3
for n in range(num_products):
Xvalues_[n] = np.array([(-2,0,2), (0,2,3),(-2,0,2)])
Xprobabilities[n] = np.array([(0.4,0.2,0.4), (0.2,0.4,0.4),(0.4,0.4,0.2)])
```

Comment: `failed` is not an acceptable question.:)  We require more detail. What is wrong, other than bad indentation and unitialized `Xvalues_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to *do* with it so this is just printing out the result for each one

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete 

Xvalues = np.array([(-2,0,2), (0,2,3),(-2,0,2)])
Xprobabilities = np.array([(0.4,0.2,0.4), (0.2,0.4,0.4),(0.4,0.4,0.2)])
for values,probabilities in zip(Xvalues, Xprobabilities):
    distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values,probabilities))
    print(distrib.rvs(size=10))
```

Comment: @ecembv if this solved your question please upvote and mark as answered!